# Automate pbrun /bin/su

Tags: shell, unix, automation, sh

I am trying to automate a script where I need to use `pbrun /bin/su` but for some reason it is not passing thru the `pbrun` as my code below.

```
. ~/.bash_profile
pbrun /bin/su - content
c h 1
hpsvn up file path
```

I am executing this from an external `.sh` file that is pointing to this scripts file but it is not running, if I do it in putty manually mode it works but if I run it from automate script it is not working, There is a difference between the `$PATH` but I don't know what relation does that has with the problem.

Comment: Are you expecting `c h 1` and `hpsvn ...` to be run under the `pbrun su` context? Because that's not how it works in a script. In an interactive session the `su` starts an interactive shell and takes over input until you exit it. In a script the `su` sees no input and immediately exits and the next lines are back in the original context.

Comment: Yes, it even actually works if I run this commands manually in putty, but for some reason it is not working running from the .bat file. I found that there is a difference in the $PATH, the value if it is run from the .bat doesn't has the /usr/kerberos/bin path whenever the manually way it shows that value, does this has something to do with the error?

Comment: Run the commands manually but right after the `pbrun su` command hit `ctrl-d` or type `exit` and hit enter to exit the `su` shell and see if things work correctly. Because *that's* the environment in the script. If you need `c h 1` and `hpsvn ...` to run *under* the `su` session then you need to give them *as arguments* to `su` (through `-c bash -c '....'` or similar).

Comment: Yes it works, after typing the pbrun bin/su - content it takes me to the content folder where I need to run this commands, if I don't run this pbrun content, it won't allow me to execute due permissions. That is why I always need to put the pbrun or if there is other way so it can be from the .bat file I will appreciate any documentation or suggestion

Comment: You missed the point. When you run `pbrun` *manually* you are starting a new `su` shell session. When you run `pbrun` in the *script* that **doesn't** happen. The `su` in the script **exits** immediately as it has no terminal to attach to for an interactive session. You **cannot** use it from a script the same way you use it interactively. It doesn't work like that. Look around this site this comes up a lot. You need to give `su` a **single** command on its command line that it can run for script purposes (or use a here document and the shell's ability to read commands from standard input).